# How to properly run Powershell scripts containing BITS operations from Task Scheduler?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, scheduled-task, bits, powershell-v5.0

I am trying to perform an automatic backup of some files and folders based on a configuration. This is done using Powershell 5 which in turn relies on Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS). E.g.:

```
Start-BitsTransfer $Source\* $Destination -RetryInterval 60 -RetryTimeout 600
```

Powershell scripts are run using a bat:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted .\Main.ps1
```

The batch is executed using a Scheduled Task:

```
User account: AD service account
Run: whether user is logged on or not
```

When I run the batch directly using the same account set on scheduled task, it runs perfectly. When I run it from the Task scheduler, BITS operations issue the following error:

> The operation being requested was not performed because the user has
>   not logged on to the network. The specified service does not exist.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800704DD)

I tried to change the user for BITS service, by setting it to the same service account I use for the scheduled task, but the service does not start anymore:

> The Background Intelligent Transfer Service service failed to start
>   due to the following error: 
>  The account specified for this service is
>   different from the account specified for other services running in the
>   same process.

Going back to the scheduled task, I have changed to run "only when user is logged on". Of course, this would make sense only if I set autologon on this user (otherwise, it will not run if not logged in).

**Question:** How can I automate a backup using BITS without relying on tricks such as autologon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're only going to be able to run that script when you're logged in.  From the MS documentation "Using Windows Powershell to Create BITS Transfer Jobs" found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663885(v=vs.85).aspx).

> When you use *-BitsTransfer cmdlets from within a process that runs in
>   a noninteractive context, such as a Windows service, you may not be
>   able to add files to BITS jobs, which can result in a suspended state.
>   For the job to proceed, the identity that was used to create a
>   transfer job must be logged on. For example, when creating a BITS job
>   in a PowerShell script that was executed as a Task Scheduler job, the
>   BITS transfer will never complete unless the Task Scheduler's task
>   setting "Run only when user is logged on" is enabled.

Try using [robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) instead.

Comment: Yes, `robocopy` is much better as it covers everything I need (progress and retrials) without the need of interactive context. Also, BITS requires custom code for deep copy of directories. Thanks.